# Make mui autocomplete persist the input value after selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After typing a value and selecting an option in Material-UI Autocomplete with Multiple, the entered value is cleared.

[image]

Is there a way to make AutoComplete persist the typed value even after selection? Like the one bellow...

[image]

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cv1f5

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Tags() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        //defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) approach for the input value using the `inputValue` and `onInputChange` props. This allows you to control the input value at all times. Material-UI will call `onInputChange` when it thinks the value should change, and Material-UI passes a reason of "input", "reset", or "clear" (see `onInputChange` in the [props documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props)). You want to ignore the "reset" changes.

Here's a modified version of your sandbox:

```
export default function ControlledInputValue() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, value, reason) => {
          if ( event && event.type === 'blur' ) {
            setInputValue('');
          } else if ( reason !== 'reset' ) {
            setInputValue(value);
          }
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete controlled inputValue]

Comment: yes but not really, this approach will not clear the input on blur event...

Comment: I'd expect the search options to remain open but when I'm using disableCloseOnSelect it doesn't work (MUI v5), whereas it works in your example ..

Answer (score 2):

add `clearOnBlur={false}`

```
     <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        value={inputValue}
        clearOnBlur={false}
        inputValue={inputValue}
```

the best solution i found is you can use

`freeSolo`

```
  <Autocomplete
     freeSolo
```

prop to persist users inputed Value
some thing like this

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/19663#issuecomment-585500644